# NewtonJson.Parse com aspas pelo meio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, json

Tenho na base de dados uma coluna do tipo `varchar` que leva um JSON. Essa coluna é a descrição de uma empresa, mas em 4 idiomas. A lógica que tenho é a seguinte:

```
{  
    "PT":"Descrição com "aspas" quebra o meu código",  
    "ES":" ",  
    "FR":"fr ",  
    "EN":" en"  
}
```

Como faço para o JSON` ser lido corretamente quando tenho aspas na descrição da empresa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa "escapar" as aspas que você tem na sua string usando a barra invertida `\` antes das aspas.

```
{  
    "PT":"Descrição com \"aspas\" quebra o meu código",  
    "ES":" ",  
    "FR":"fr ",  
    "EN":" en"  
}
```

Comment: Foi disso que me apercebi e já perguntei aos gurus como posso adicionar isso usando regex nesta questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187190/montar-regex-para-alterar-string-json

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) e o [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) do próprio NewtonSoft.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var text = "{\"SomeResponse\":{\"FIrstAttribute\":8,\"SecondAttribute\":\"On\",\"ThirdAttribute\":{\"Id\":2,\"FirstName\":\"Okkie\",\"Name\":\"Bokkie\",\"Street\":\"\",\"StreetNumber\":null,\"PostCode\":\"\",\"City\":\"\",\"Country\":\"}}}";
        var token = JToken.Parse(text);
        var json = JObject.Parse((string) token);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/ReadXml.cs).

Fonte da [resposta do Jon Skeet no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26406504/221800).

Desde o .NET Core há uma [solução melhor para JSON](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e cada versão melhora mais, no .NET 6 está fantástico.