# Montar RegEx para alterar string json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, regex

Tenho a seguinte string, que na verdade vai ser tratado como um `json`, guardado numa coluna na base de dados no meu `SQL Server`:

```
{"PT":"adssadsadsd "asdada"","ES":"","FR":"","EN":""}
```

Como faço para alterar, de forma automática, a *string* para ter o seguinte aspeto:

```
{"PT":"adssadsadsd \"asdada\"","ES":"","FR":"","EN":""}
```

Quero fazer essa alteração no *Controller* do meu projeto *MVC*. Preciso disto pois tenho registos na base de dados que estão mal formatados e depois não consigo buscar as informações da maneira correta.

Comment: antes de montar seu JSON você pode chamar `string.Replace("\"", "\\\"")`

Comment: isso não vai mudar todas as aspas em vez de mudar só as que eu mencionei?

Comment: se você colocar depois de montado o Json a resposta é sim.. , se poss[ivel coloque o codigo que gera o JSON ai posso te dar certeza.

Comment: mas não consigo fazer o Parse por causa dessas aspas, dá-me exception

Comment: você está guardando o JSON inteiro no seu campo da base de dados? é isso?

Comment: exato! não sei é o melhor, mas já estava assim quando peguei no projeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Montei in Fiddle com uma ideia](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8t3ceV). Não é exatamente a melhor, mas se baseia na ideia de que, se eu trocar as aspas iniciais por apóstrofos e serializar, o desserializador JSON vai entender que a aspa faz parte do campo, e não um delimitador.

```
public static IEnumerable<String> RetirarAspas(string jsonString) 
{
    var regex = new Regex("(\")([\\w]+)(\")(:)(\")([\\w\\s\"]*)(\"),?");
    var teste = regex.Matches(jsonString);

    foreach (Match match in teste) 
    {
        String linha = "";

        for (int i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++) 
        {
            if (match.Groups[i].ToString() == "\"") 
                linha += "'";
            else
                linha += match.Groups[i].ToString();
        }

        yield return linha;
    }
}
```

Aí posso montar o JSON assim:

```
    var testeJson = "{";
    foreach (var linha in lista)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(linha);
        testeJson += linha + ", ";
    }

    testeJson += "}";

    var jsonDesserializado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(testeJson);
    Console.Write(jsonDesserializado);
```

Comment: como faço para incluir '-' nas strings?

Comment: Só alterar a expressão regular: `new Regex("(\")([\\w-]+)(\")(:)(\")([\\w\\s\"-]*)(\"),?");`